# Troubleshooting steps for ssh connecting to first AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, ssh, amazon-ec2, cloud

Can I get some troubleshooting advice connecting to my first AWS (ssh) instance?  This is almost certainly user error (no familiarity with AWS!!) despite being a Linux admin by day job.  I cannot connect to my instance's public IP with putty, and telnet tests to the server from my desktop on port 22 time out.  I've not (yet) found a port check on the internet I can use to prove it's not my networking (though I disabled both windows firewall, and my cable modem's firewall).

Public DNS
ec2-54-164-144-29.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Public IP
54.164.144.29
Private IPs
172.31.30.40

My security group permits access to my server via ssh (22) from 0.0.0.0/0.

Network Interface eth0:

Interface ID
eni-824b719e
VPC ID
vpc-3bddcf5f
Attachment Owner
554173555573
Attachment Status
attached
Attachment Time
Tue Oct 11 13:51:21 GMT-400 2016
Delete on Terminate
true
Private IP Address
172.31.30.40
Private DNS Name
ip-172-31-30-40.ec2.internal
Elastic IP Address
54.164.144.29
Source/Dest. Check
true
Description
Primary network interface
Security Groups
ssh-http only

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like a security group issue.  SSHD seems to be answering client.  So what I think is you need to create the key pair.  And download the .pem file and add that .pem file to putty before you can ssh into the EC2 instance.

For more detail information, you can see AWS doc here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html